# Program based on issuing a book in library

Tags: python

The library at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry has computerized its book issuing process. The relevant information is provided as text from standard input in three parts: information about books, information about borrowers and information about checkouts. Each part has a specific line format, described below.

Information about books
Line format: Accession Number~Title

Information about borrowers
Line format: Username~Full Name

Information about checkouts
Line format: Username~Accession Number~Due Date
Note: Due Date is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

You may assume that the data is internally consistent. For every checkout, there is a corresponding username and accession number in the input data, and no book is simultaneously checked out by two people.
Each section of the input starts with a line containing a single keyword. The first section begins with a line containing Books. The second section begins with a line containing Borrowers. The third section begins with a line containing Checkouts. The end of the input is marked by a line containing EndOfInput.
Write a Python program to read the data as described above and print out details about books that have been checked out. Each line should describe to one currently issued book in the following format:
Due Date~Full Name~Accession Number~Title 
Your output should be sorted in increasing order of due date. For books due on the same date, sort in increasing order of full name.
Here is a sample input and its corresponding output.
Sample Input
Books APM-001~Advanced Potion-Making GWG-001~Gadding With Ghouls APM-002~Advanced Potion-Making DMT-001~Defensive Magical Theory DMT-003~Defensive Magical Theory GWG-002~Gadding With Ghouls DMT-002~Defensive Magical Theory Borrowers SLY2301~Hannah Abbott SLY2302~Euan Abercrombie SLY2303~Stewart Ackerley SLY2304~Bertram Aubrey SLY2305~Avery SLY2306~Malcolm Baddock SLY2307~Marcus Belby SLY2308~Katie Bell SLY2309~Sirius Orion Black Checkouts SLY2304~DMT-002~2019-03-27 SLY2301~GWG-001~2019-03-27 SLY2308~APM-002~2019-03-14 SLY2303~DMT-001~2019-04-03 SLY2301~GWG-002~2019-04-03 EndOfInput 
Sample Output
2019-03-14~Katie Bell~APM-002~Advanced Potion-Making 2019-03-27~Bertram Aubrey~DMT-002~Defensive Magical Theory 2019-03-27~Hannah Abbott~GWG-001~Gadding With Ghouls 2019-04-03~Hannah Abbott~GWG-002~Gadding With Ghouls 2019-04-03~Stewart Ackerley~DMT-001~Defensive Magical Theory

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Home Work problem straight away asked in forums without any attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Works. I've coded it and got 6 out of 6 tests passed. Hope this helps y'all. Happy coding!

```
def borrowers_input(b):
    x=input()
    while x!='Checkouts':
        x=x.split('~')
        b.append(x)
        x=input()

def checkouts_input(c):
    x=input()
    while x!='EndOfInput':
        x=x.split('~')
        c.append(x)
        x=input()

def output():
    global books,borrower,checkout
    date=[]
    uname=[]
    name=[]
    Anum=[]
    title=[]
    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        date.append(checkout[i][2])

    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        uname.append(checkout[i][0])

    for i in range(0,len(uname)):
        for j in range(0,len(borrower)):
            if(uname[i] == borrower[j][0]):
                name.append(borrower[j][1])

    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        Anum.append(checkout[i][1])

    for i in range(0,len(Anum)):
        for j in range(0,len(books)):
            if(Anum[i] == books[j][0]):
                title.append(books[j][1])

    final=[]
    for i in range(0,len(checkout)):
        final.append(date[i]+'~'+name[i]+'~'+Anum[i]+'~'+title[i])
    final.sort()
    for i in range(0,len(final)):
        print(final[i])


books=[]
borrower=[]
checkout=[]
x=input()
x=input()
while x!='Borrowers':
    x=x.split('~')
    books.append(x)
    x=input()
borrowers_input(borrower)
borrower.sort()
checkouts_input(checkout)
output()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 str1=input()                           #do check indentation(must!!)

 (lst1,lst2,lst3)=([],[],[])

while str1!="EndOfInput":

if str1=="Books":
    while True:
        str1=input()
        if str1!="Borrowers":
            lst1.append(str1.split('~'))
        else:
            break
if str1=="Borrowers":
    while True:
        str1=input()
        if str1!="Checkouts":
            lst2.append(str1.split('~'))
        else:
            break

if str1=="Checkouts":
    while True:
        str1=input()
        if str1!="EndOfInput":
            lst3.append(str1.split('~'))
        else:
            break
l1=dict(lst1)
l2=dict(lst2)
l3=sorted(lst3,key=lambda t:t[0])
ll=[]

for i in range(len(l3)):
  ll.append([((l3[i][2],l2.get(l3[i][0]),l3[i][1],l1.get(l3[i][1])))])

  fl=sorted(ll, key=lambda t:t[0])
  for j in range(len(fl)):
     for k in fl[j]:
        print(k[0],k[1],k[2],k[3],sep="~")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal for the code:

```
l=[]

due_date=[]

full_name=[]

while True:

    x=input()
    l.append(x)
    if x=="EndOfInput":
            inde=l.index("Books")
            inde2=l.index("Borrowers")
            inde3=l.index("Checkouts")
            l1=l[inde:inde2:1]
            l2=l[inde2:inde3:1]
            l3=l[inde3:len(l)-1:1]
            d1={l1[0]:l1[1::]}
            d2={l2[0]:l2[1::]}
            d3={l3[0]:l3[1::]}
            break


for e in d3.values():

    for j in e:
        x=j.split("~")
        x1=x[0] 
        x2=x[2] 
        for e1 in d2.values():
            for j1 in e1:
                xx=j1.split("~")
                xx1=xx[1]  
                if x1 in xx[0]:
                    due_date.append(x2)
                    full_name.append(xx1)

asscnu_title=[]

for e in d3.values():

    for j in e:
        x2=j.split("~")
        x2=x2[1]  
        for e1 in d1.values():
            for j1 in e1:
                if x2 in j1:
                    asscnu_title.append(j1)   

full_names=[]

for e in full_name:

    full_names.append("~{}".format(e))

asscnu_titles=[]

for e in asscnu_title:

    asscnu_titles.append("~{}".format(e))

final=zip(due_date,full_names,asscnu_titles)

final=list(final)

final.sort()

for e in final:

    print("".join(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sorting the checkouts list in date order.
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        l=lst[i].find("2019")
        for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
            if lst[i][l:] > lst[j][l:]:
                (lst[i],lst[j])=(lst[j],lst[i])
    return lst

#sorting the names.
def sortn(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
            if lst[i][8:] > lst[j][8:]:
                (lst[i],lst[j])=(lst[j],lst[i])
    return lst

#sorting the duplicates in date according to the question.
def check_dup(lst1,lst2,lst3):
    l=lst1[0].find("2019")
    for i in range(len(lst1)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(lst1)):

            #if dates are same then check names
            if lst1[i][l:]==lst1[j][l:]:
                for k in range(len(lst2)):
                    if lst2[k][:7]==lst1[i][:7]:
                        n1=k
                    if lst2[k][:7]==lst1[j][:7]:
                        n2=k

                if n1>n2:
                    (lst1[i],lst1[j])=(lst1[j],lst1[i])

            #if the names are also same then check
            if lst1[i][:8]==lst1[j][:8] and lst1[i][15:]==lst1[j][15:]:
                for k in range(len(lst3)):
                    if lst3[k][:7]==lst1[i][8:15]:
                        m1=k
                    elif lst3[k][:7]==lst1[j][8:15]:
                        m2=k
                if m1>m2:
                    (lst1[i],lst1[j])=(lst1[j],lst1[i])
    return lst1

s=input()
s=input()
Books=[]
while ( s != 'Borrowers' ) :
    Books.append( s )
s=input()

Books.sort()                                   

Borrowers=[]
s=input()
while ( s != 'Checkouts' ) :
Borrowers.append( s )
s=input()

Borrowers=sortn(Borrowers)
s=input()
checkouts=[]
while(s != 'EndOfInput'):
    checkouts.append(s)
    s=input()

checkouts=sortl(checkouts)

checkouts=check_dup(checkouts,Borrowers,Books)

#printing acc to question.
for i in checkouts:
    l=checkouts[0].find("2019")
    print(i[l:],end="~")
    for j in Borrowers:
        if i[:7]==j[:7]:
            print(j[8:],end="~")
            break

    for k in Books:
        if i[8:15]==k[:7]:
            print(k)
            break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x=0       #do check indentation(must!!)
users={}
books={}
checkouts={}
while(True):
   s=input()
   if(s=="EndOfInput"):
      break
   if(s=="Books"):

        x=1
        continue
   if(s=="Borrowers"):

        x=2
        continue
   l=s.split("~")
   if(s=="Checkouts"):
        x=3
        continue
   if(x==1):

        books.__setitem__(l[0],l[1])
   if(x==2) :

        users.__setitem__(l[0],l[1])
   if(x==3):
        if(l[2]  not in checkouts.keys()):
            checkouts.__setitem__(l[2],[[users[l[0]],str(l[1]),books[l[1]]]])
        else:
            checkouts[l[2]].append([users[l[0]],str(l[1]),books[l[1]]])
for i in sorted(checkouts.keys()):
      checkouts[i].sort()
      for j in range(len(checkouts[i])):
         print(i,(*checkouts[i][j]),sep="~")
```